# Easy Cron Service?

Tags: php, cron, iron

I'm building a web-app that allows user to create notifications, with a custom date-time.

I considered using Cron-Jobs but the task of adding, editing, and deleting seems overly complicated. Especially in the case of 1 time notifications.

I looked at Iron.io but am unsure if it's the best solution for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Can anyone recommend a solution which would allow me to easily add, remove, from a schedule to run PHP scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Run the cronjob every minute and check if any work needs to be done. Don't configure individual cronjobs for your users.

Comment: :-( GoDaddy limits cron jobs to max of once every 5 mins, unless you upgrade to virtual server. What hosting do you use and does it allow cron job every minutes?

Comment: If by chance you can configure 5 cronjobs, just do a `sleep(60)` to wait for the next minute at the start one or more times and thus run every minute.